# Scrapy one item with multiple parsing functions

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy with python to scrape a website and I face some difficulties with filling the item that I have created.

The products are properly scraped and everything is working well as long as the info is located within the `response.xpath` mentioned in the `for loop`.

'trend' and 'number' are properly added to the Item using ItemLoader.

However, the date of the product is not located within the response.xpath cited below but in the `response.css` as a title : `response.css('title')`

```
import scrapy
import datetime
from trends.items import Trend_item
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

#Initiate the spider

class trendspiders(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'milk'
    start_urls = ['https://thewebsiteforthebestmilk/ireland/2022-03-16/7/']

    def parse(self, response):

       for milk_unique in response.xpath('/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/section[1]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr'):
                l = ItemLoader(item=Milk_item(), selector=milk_unique, response=response)
                l.add_css('milk', 'a::text')
                l.add_css('number', 'span.small.text-muted::text')

            return l.load_item()
```

How can I add the 'date' to my item please (found in `response.css('title')`?

I have tried to add `l.add_css('date', "response.css('title')")`in the for loop but it returns an error.

Should I create a new parsing function? If yes then how to send the info to the same Item?

I hope I’ve made myself clear.

Thank you very much for your help,

Comment: please include either a url to the site you are scraping or a sample of the html from the site that demonstrates what you are referring to.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. I have modified the code to give you more details about what I am trying to achieve. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `date` is outside of the selector you are using for each row, what you should do is extract that first before your for loop, since it doesn't need to be updated on each iteration.

Then with your item loader you can just use `l.add_value` to load it with the rest of the fields.

For example:

```
class trendspiders(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'trends'
    start_urls = ['https://getdaytrends.com/ireland/2022-03-16/7/']

    def parse(self, response):
        date_str = response.xpath("//title/text()").get()
        for trend_unique in response.xpath('/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/section[1]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr'):
            l = ItemLoader(item=Trend_item(), selector=trend_unique, response=response)
            l.add_css('trend', 'a::text')
            l.add_css('number', 'span.small.text-muted::text')
            l.add_value('date', date_str)
            yield l.load_item()
```

Answer (score 0):

If `response.css('title').get()` gives you the answer you need, why not use the same CSS with `add_css`:

```
l.add_css('date', 'title')
```

Also, `.add_css('date', "response.css('title')")` is invalid because the second argument a valid CSS selector.

Comment: Where would you use it please? As  the `title` for the 'date'  is not located within the`response.xpath('/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/section[1]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr')` when crawled the spider returns an error. Am I missing something? Thank you again for your help!